# Service.type has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class ServicesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var services = [Service]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //load services data
        loadServices()
    }

    private func loadServices(){
        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "blank")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "blank1")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "blank2")

        guard let Service1 = Service(titled: "blank", description:"Test", imageName: photo1) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate Service1")
        }
        guard let Service2 = Service(titled: "blank1", description:"Test", imageName: photo2) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate Service1")
        }
        guard let Service3 = Service(titled: "blank2", description:"Test", imageName: photo3) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate Service1")
        }
        services += [Service1,Service2,Service3]

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return services.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "ServicesTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ServicesTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ServicesTableViewCell.")
        }

        // Fetches the appropriate service for the data source layout.
        let services = Service[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = service.titled
        cell.photoImageView.image = service.image
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = service.description

        return cell
    }
```

I keep getting the error Service.type has no subscript members. I am trying to input this data into a table view controller, this is the code inside of the table view controller, I can post the cell code and the service.swift file also if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should change this:

```
let services = Service[indexPath.row] // this is a class, not an array
```

in

```
let service = services[indexPath.row]
```

---

I also see that you initialize your `Service` passing an argument called `imageName` of type `UIImage`, so it may be confusing for you and I guess might be a problem in your `cellForRowAt`, because of:

```
cell.photoImageView.image = service.image
```

hence, be sure you have declared such property (image != imageName) in your `Service`.

Comment: Andrea is correct. The expression `Service[indexPath.row]` makes no sense, since `Service` is a class. You have defined an array `services` that contains an array of `Service` objects. That's what you need, and it should indeed work.

Comment: logically her solution makes sense but something is still wrong

Comment: I ended up restructuring the code I didn't like it thanks though @Andrea Mugnaini